# What are the drawbacks of create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, production

I have to build a frontend project from scratch.

This project is ambitious and will last for a long time. My main goal in this first weeks of development will be to start on a good basis.

Therefore, i'm wondering if create-react-app is a good option because it's easy to begin with and this toolbox is optimized for production.

However, how modular my project will be if i use this solution ?

Does anybody know if some drawback can appear on project using CRA ?

My main worry is about bundler.

If the project is getting bigger and bigger, do i have to optimize the webpack config of CRA ?

Isn't better to create my project from scratch with my own bundler configuration ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CRA is a lightweight environment which generates the HTML on the client side (browser).

Which means it goes under the **advantages and drawbacks** of **Client Side Renderding** (google it).

> For CRA advantages see [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/).

Disadvantages:

- Opinionated setup (like almost all tools).
- Hard to configure.

> I don't think there are more interesting drawbacks to talk about.

---

#### Very important side note: the developing cycle should be decoupled from the production environment.

There are some fundamental issues that I want to tackle because I see many questions resemble this one.

React is all about **Composition** and **Isolation** (see [Design Principles](https://reactjs.org/docs/design-principles.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper), [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html)). Meaning that your React components **should work on any environment**

So, when developing an app, you should **focus** on developing in **isolation**, therefore developing with tools like [**Storybook**](https://storybook.js.org/) is actually the only thing you need.

My opinionated developing cycle of a new project:

0. Decide on any environment (like CRA/Gatsby/Next etc.)
1. Develop components in isolation (like with Storybook).
2. Push changed to production environment.
3. Repeat 1-2 till you get to bottle neck (For example you found that CSR isn't working well for you application).
4. **Switch** production environment (remember that your components should work on **any** environment). Goto 1.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you for answering, it is really helpful. 

I don't need Server Side Rendering for this app, so CRA seems to be a good option.

I edited my post to be more precise on my worries

Comment: I thought the question was about using `create-react-app` vs doing a react project from scratch.

Comment: @FedericoCapaldo mentioning the advantages is enough, or you can elaborate?

Comment: What's an example of "Hard to configure"?

Comment: @stk1234 Every feature that not supported in CRA is hard to configure, you can reference any tool that helps with CRA configuration like https://github.com/dilanx/craco

Answer (score 0):

For me, the top reason why I won't use CRA is because there is no option for a development / staging build. `react-scripts build` will always set the environment to production and produce a minified build, not suited to host in a dev / staging environment.

Comment: You could just run the standard `npm start` script if you want a dev server (i.e. not production)